# How to implement jump command in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine, interpreter

i am trying to make a bytecode virtual machine/interpreter or i dont know how to call it, but i am having problems when trying to implement the jump if equal Operations.
This is my main file:

```
const fileUtils = require('./fileUtils'); // Assuming the module file is named fileUtils.js
const { HTD, DTH } = require('./Utils')

let regs = ["00", "00", "f0", "00", ["00"]] // RAX, RBX, RCX, RNV, RSV
let inst = fileUtils.RIF('./instset.8bin');
console.log("Inst Set: ", inst); 

// 16.32kb
ram = ["00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00"]
RLEN = ram.length
console.log(ram.length)
function endProcc(code, ramq)
{
    if (code == 0)
    {
        console.log("Procc Succ")
        console.log("RAX:", regs[0])
        console.log("RBX:", regs[1])
        console.log("RCX:", regs[2])
        console.log("RNV:", regs[3])
        console.log("RSV:", regs[4])
        if(ramq == 1)
        {
            const cols = 8;
            let arr = ram
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                const rowIndex = Math.floor(i / cols);
                const colIndex = i % cols;
                const element = arr[i];

                // Print the element at the specified grid position
                process.stdout.write(`${element} `);

                // If it's the last element of the row, move to the next line
                if (colIndex === cols - 1) {
                    process.stdout.write('\n');
                }
            }
            
        }
        process.exit(0)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('\x1b[31m\nSome Error Occured, check out documentation, and review your codebase')
        process.exit(1)
    }
    
}

// for (let i = 0; i < inst.length; i+=0)
let i = 0
while (i < inst.length)
{
    if (inst[i+1] == "10") //SYSCALL SPrint
    {
        console.log("SPrint")
        console.log(regs[4])
        i+=2
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "11") //SYSCALL NPrint
    {
        console.log("NPrint")
        console.log(regs[3])
        i+=2
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "ff") //SYSCALL HLT
    {
        console.log("HLT\n")
        endProcc(0, 0)
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "12") //SYSCALL SWP
    {
        console.log("SWP")
        placeholder = regs[0]
        regs[0] = regs[1]
        regs[1] = placeholder
        i+=2    
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "13") //SYSCALL SWPC
    {
        console.log("SWPC")
        placeholder = regs[0]
        regs[0] = regs[2]
        regs[2] = placeholder
        i+=2    
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "14") //SYSCALL SWPRNV
    {
        console.log("SWPRNV")
        placeholder = regs[2]
        regs[2] = regs[3]
        regs[3] = placeholder
        i+=2    
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "15") //SYSCALL RSVPUSH
    {
        console.log("RSVPUSH")
        regs[4].push(regs[2])
        i+=2    
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "16") //SYSCALL RSVPOP
    {
        console.log("RSVPOP")
        regs[4].pop()
        i+=2
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "17") //SYSCALL ADD
    {
        console.log("ADD")
        regs[2] = DTH(HTD(regs[0]) + HTD(regs[1]))
        i+=2
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "18") //SYSCALL SUB
    {
        console.log("SUB")
        regs[2] = DTH(HTD(regs[0]) - HTD(regs[1]))
        i+=2
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "19") //SYSCALL MUL
    {
        regs[2] = DTH(HTD(regs[0]) * HTD(regs[1]))
        i+=2
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "0a") //SYSCALL EQ
    {
        console.log("EQ")
        // if (regs[0] == regs[1])
        // {
        //     ram[RLEN-1] = "01"
        //     console.log(i)
        //     i = HTD(inst[i+2]) -1
        //     console.log(i)
        //     console.log(inst[i])
        // }
        console.log("EQ");
        if (regs[0] === regs[1]) {
        ram[RLEN-1] = "01";
        i = DTH(inst[i+2]) - 1; // Use DTH instead of HTD
        } else {
        ram[RLEN-1] = "00";
        }
        i += 3;
        // else 
        // {
        //     ram[RLEN-1] = "00"
        // }
        // i+=3
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "0b") //SYSCALL NEQ
    {
        console.log("NEQ")
        if (regs[0] != regs[1])
        {
            ram[RLEN-1] = "01"
            i = HTD(inst[i+2])

        }
        else 
        {
            ram[RLEN-1] = "00"
        }
        i+=3
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "0c") //SYSCALL GT
    {
        console.log("GT")
        if (regs[0] > regs[1])
        {
            ram[RLEN-1] = "01"
            i = HTD(inst[i+2]) - 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            ram[RLEN-1] = "00"
        }
        i+=3
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "0d") //SYSCALL LT
    {
        console.log("LT")
        if (regs[0] < regs[1])
        {
            ram[RLEN-1] = "01"
            i = HTD(inst[i+2])
        }
        else 
        {
            ram[RLEN-1] = "00"
        }
        i+=3
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "20") //ADDR STR
    {
        console.log("STR ADDR:", inst[i+2])
        ram[HTD(inst[i+2])-1] = regs[2]
        i+=3
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "21") //ADDR LD
    {
        console.log("LD ADDR:", inst[i+2])
        regs[2] = ram[HTD(inst[i+2])-1]
        i+=3
    }
    else if (inst[i+1] == "22") //ADDR SVC
    {
        console.log("Save RCX: ", inst[i+2])
        regs[2] = inst[i+2]
        i+=3
    }
    
    else
    {
        console.log('\x1b[31m\nERR: ICE:01\nInternal Compilation Error: Unrecognized token in script \n Unrecognizable:  "', inst[i], '"  token num:', (i+1).toString())
        endProcc(1)
    }
}
```

this is my fileUtils file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  RHF: function(filePath) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8').trim();
    return data.split(' ');
  },

  RIF: function(filePath) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8').trim();
    return data.split(/\s+/);
  },

  WHF: function(filePath, dataArray) {
    const data = dataArray.join(' ');
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, data);
  }
};
```

this is my Utils file:

```
module.exports = {
  HTD: function(hexString) { 
     return parseInt(hexString, 16);
    },

  DTH: function(decimalNumber) {
   let hexString = decimalNumber.toString(16);
  if (hexString.length % 2 !== 0) {
    hexString = '0' + hexString;
  }
  return hexString;
  }
};
```

and this is my instset.8bin file:(its a custom filetype)

```
00 0a 06 00 ff 00 11 00 ff
```

and this is the ouput im getting:

Inst Set:  [
'00', '0a', '06',
'00', 'ff', '00',
'11', '00', 'ff'
]
512
EQ
EQ

ERR: ICE:01
Internal Compilation Error: Unrecognized token in script
Unrecognizable:  " ff "  token num: 9

Some Error Occured, check out documentation, and review your codebase

the code above, i have no clue what else to try

Comment: Which part of the code is supposed to be implementing the conditional jump?